# Microsoft Graph Authentication error AADSTS70000 code_verifier does not match code_challenge

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have multiple pages that authenticate via Microsoft Graph.  One doesn't work.  It returns a `(400) Bad Request`, with the error_description of `AADSTS70000: The provided 'code_verifier' input value does not match the original 'code_challenge.'`

All Redirect URL's are defined under my Microsoft Applications.  Except for the URI, they are the same.

I cannot find anything that actually says what they mean be `code_verifier` and `code_challenge`.  Since I never pass any parms by those names, they must be referring to one of the other parms being passed in before and after the login.  But I really need to know what they refer to so I can attempt to figure out what the real issue seems to be.

I have seen several posts claiming a trailing slash is required, but I don't have this on any of my Redirect URI's, and most of them work.

Here is the initiating request:

`href="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={redacted}&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://wrmatthiesen.com/ApprovedContact/InviteeSignup.aspx&scope=openid offline_access User.Read Calendars.ReadWrite Contacts.Read Mail.Send& nonce=mauth:-6:Y:Y;1b803d44-f70b-4fed-b6c3-bc3afdb55646& state=mauth:-6:Y:Y;1b803d44-f70b-4fed-b6c3-bc3afdb55646"`

Here is the follow up request once I have received the code:

`code=Mabb3f2bb-25b0-8e3b-541e-9763dd1e4136&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fwrmatthiesen.com%2fApprovedContact%2fInviteeSignup.aspx&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id={redacted}&client_secret={redacted}&scope=openid+offline_access+User.Read+Calendars.ReadWrite+Contacts.Read+Mail.Send`

Comment: Are you using a state param and are you passing this value with both the initial and secondary token request?

Comment: Yes, I pass the state param the same way for each request. I believe I am making the successful requests and the failed request exactly the same. (obviously not though, because of the error).  That's why I am trying to narrow down what specifically they are referring to by code_verifier and code_challenge.  It is probably something suttle that I am just overlooking.

Comment: Can you add the HTTP URIs you're calling to your question? This error implies that something changed between the two auth steps. Typically this happens when you have a change in the state param or you're using different redirect URIs.

Comment: URI's added above

Answer (score 0):

1) Your initial request included several unencoded strings that include special characters.

2) You have a couple of space your query string: `& nonce` and `& state`

You're first URL should look like this:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://wrmatthiesen.com/ApprovedContact/InviteeSignup.aspx&scope=openid+offline_access+User.Read+Calendars.ReadWrite+Contacts.Read+Mail.Send&nonce=mauth%3A-6%3AY%3AY%3B1b803d44-f70b-4fed-b6c3-bc3afdb55646&state=mauth%3A-6%3AY%3AY%3B1b803d44-f70b-4fed-b6c3-bc3afdb55646`

The components here being:

- client_id: `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`
- response_mode: `form_post`
- response_type: `code`
- redirect_uri: `https%3A%2F%2Fwrmatthiesen.com%2FApprovedContact%2FInviteeSignup.aspx`
- scope: `openid+offline_access+User.Read+Calendars.ReadWrite+Contacts.Read+Mail.Send`
- nonce: `mauth%3A-6%3AY%3AY%3B1b803d44-f70b-4fed-b6c3-bc3afdb55646`
- state: `mauth%3A-6%3AY%3AY%3B1b803d44-f70b-4fed-b6c3-bc3afdb55646`

On the second call, your `POST` body looks correct:

- code: `Mabb3f2bb-25b0-8e3b-541e-9763dd1e4136`
- redirect_uri: `https%3A%2F%2Fwrmatthiesen.com%2FApprovedContact%2FInviteeSignup.aspx`
- grant_type: `authorization_code`
- client_id: `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`
- client_secret: `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`
- scope: `openid+offline_access+User.Read+Calendars.ReadWrite+Contacts.Read+Mail.Send

Comment: Unfortunately, those differences also exist coming from the pages that works, and my test harness.

Comment: Sorry, hit enter too soon. -- The spaces before the parameters were from the copy and paste into here, so they don't really exist.  And unfortunately, all the other encoding differences also exist coming from the pages that works, and my test harness. I have always used spaces between the scopes on the first request, and whether they are ' ' or %20, they work.  Same with the & parm separator.  Whether it is & or &amp; it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have been passing in a nonce parameter since I have been doing this.  I just made it match my state parameter for ease.  In this situation, my nonce looked like this: "nonce=mauth:-6:Y:Y;b5a41fdb-4b42-494e-85e1-8c193006d444".

When I dropped everything except the "mauth:", it worked.

I then dropped the nonce all together, and it still worked.  So, for now, I will not pass the nonce in.